# Get referral count of each user in the same table in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have the following table :

```
| Id | referral |    
|----|----------|    
|  1 |        0 |    
|  2 |        0 |    
|  3 |        1 |    
|  4 |        2 |    
|  5 |        1 |
```

When a user has 0 in the referral columns, it means he didn't clicked on any referral link. If it has a number, it refers to the ID of another user.

So now I just want this kind of output :

```
| Id | referral | referred_count |    
|----|----------|----------------|
|  1 |        0 |              2 |  
|  2 |        0 |              1 |    
|  3 |        1 |              0 |    
|  4 |        2 |              0 |    
|  5 |        1 |              0 |
```

Is there a way to get this kind of output with only one mysql query ? I tried a lot of things but I'm getting stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*) from t t2 where t2.referral = t.id) as referred_count
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with a `JOIN` of the table to itself:

```
select r1.id, r1.referral, count(r2.referral) AS referred_count
from ref r1
left join ref r2 on r2.referral = r1.id
group by r1.id
```

Output:

```
id    referral    referred_count
1     0           2 
2     0           1 
3     1           0 
4     2           0 
5     1           0
```